# How to find specified line in textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox

How to get an specified line in an textbox and get the text from that line in an string

Comment: if you used one of these for your answer, put a green check mark it will help your acceptance rating.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim lines As String() = testing.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine)
```

then access the lines just like this

```
lines(0) // would be first line
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the text box text into an array of strings based on the line separator and then, if you have enough lines, get the line from the array:

```
    Dim asLines As String()
    Dim wLineToGet As Integer = 2
    asLines = TextBox1.Text.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    If asLines IsNot Nothing AndAlso asLines.Length >= wLineToGet Then
        MessageBox.Show("Line " & wLineToGet & " = " & asLines(wLineToGet - 1))
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("There are not enough lines in the textbox to retrieve line " & wLineToGet)
    End If
```